# How do you compute an orthogonal basis of a matrix using hmatrix?

Tags: haskell, matrix, orthogonal

`orth(somematrix)` is built into MATLAB but doesn't seem to be available in the Haskell hmatrix library.

Comment: They say use Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Algorithms.qr, but I don't know how to write `orth` in terms of `qr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra    

orth :: Field a => Matrix a -> [Vector a]
orth m = toColumns $ fst $ qr m
```

or point-free

```
orth = toColumns . fst . qr
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) has an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
orth m = toColumns u
        where (u,_,_) = compactSVD m
```

https://github.com/AlbertoRuiz/hmatrix/issues/10#issuecomment-4077403

Comment: The columns of the rotation q from the qr factorization span the whole space. If you want an orthonormal basis of the range space of the input matrix m you must take only `rank m` columns from q (the matrix rank is numerically estimated using the SVD). Alternatively you can use the compatSVD as above, but the basis vectors will be different.